# Using a certain Python version in virtualenv on MacOS

Tags: python, configuration

I have three Python version installed on my MacOs: Python 2.7.18, Python 3.9.0 and Python 3.10.

Python 2.7.18 and Python 3.9.0 are added into the Path which can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

That is OK for me. I do now want to add Python 3.10 to path. However I would like to use it inside my virtualenv.

Python 3.10 is installed under the following directory `/usr/local/opt/python@3.10`.

[image]

My project is located here `/Users/David/Documents/Project`.

I tried to use the following command (inside my project's directory): `sudo virtualenv venv --python .usr/local/opt/python@3.10`. Unfortunately it didn't work with the following error `RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='.usr/local/opt/python@3.10'`.

How can I create my virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your path to `python@3.10` has an error - it has `.` at the front indicating the current directory, try `/usr/local/opt/python@3.10`.

Comment: Thanks. I got an error again, a different one this time `RuntimeError: failed to query /usr/local/opt/python@3.10 with code 13 err: 'Permission denied'`. I used the sudo keyword.